# Excel: Time * 24 returns negative number?

Tags: excel

I have a field `D19` in time format with value `13:40:00`. Assume somone gets payed for 50 $ an hour, I want to create a formula to compute how much he has earned in that time.

Now if found [here](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Convert-Time-To-Decimal.html) that

> To convert a time to a number of hours, multiply by 24

So in this case the formula would be simply

```
= D19 * 24 * 50
```

However the formula

```
= D19 * 24
```

returns `-10,33333...`. The format of the cell where I entered the formula is a `number -> standard`. Why is it returning a negative number?

Comment: You are somehow introducing a negative day (e.g. -1) into the result. TIME(13, 40, 0) * 24 equals 13.67. 13.67+10.33 = 1 day. Probably before midnight/aftermidnight shift where you are only using the time.

Comment: @Jeeped Thank you! You were right. The number Time(13,40,0) was adding other times, one of them was from `23:30:00` to `00:00:00`. I changed it to `23:29:00` to `23:59:00` and now its working... Thank you! Please post an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Sorry that this is offtopic. I thought this is in the scope of `complex formula` as noted in the tag info. But I also understand that it is debatable if the formula is complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you multiply 13:40:00 by 24 you get 13.67, so when you take 13.67 and subtract 24 (which is one day) you get -10.33333 which is a value you got.

Are you sure you aren't subtracting one day from the value that you calculate? That would be the logical explanation.